# Is a custom executor for NioEventLoopGroup dangerous?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I want to reuse the thread pool of my worker threads in the NioEventLoopGroup of my server bootstrap.

The [NioEventLoopGroup interface](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoopGroup.html#NioEventLoopGroup-int-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) offers to use a custom executor. I'm worried to use it, because the default executor is a [special implementation](https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/util/concurrent/MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.html#75):

```
if (executor == null) {
    executor = new ThreadPerTaskExecutor(this.newDefaultThreadFactory());
}
```

The netty people usually don't write implementations without a reason. That's why I'm not sure if using a simple thread pool has any disadvantages.

Comment: Why not share the `NioEventLoopGroup` object?

Comment: good point. I didn't see that it implements Executor, but it obviously does. Thank you. But it would still be nice to know if it is dangerous or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not dangerous to use your custom `Executor` in general but I think for your use-case you should just share the same `EventLoopGroup` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The custom `Executor` is useful to share a thread pool with another part of your implementation out of Netty's scope. Believe Norman when he says: it's not dangerous.

Project Reactor supports the [same mechanism](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#fromExecutorService-java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService-) of custom `Executor`. So you can create one and share it between Reactor and Netty, in order to maximize the usage of the threads (not leave a pool underused while the other is overused). Keep in mind that sharing executors this way is suitable only for short-lived, non-blocking tasks.